# unable to compile program on dev-c++?

Tags: c++, windows, dev-c++

Downloading the new version fixed my problem thanks for the help.

I can't compile my program and I have no idea why? I have searched quite hard to find any reason why this is happening with no results. I am just trying to run the default example that dev-c++ gives you [this is what it spits out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSDHB.jpg)
This is the compile log

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\C++\test2\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\C++\test2\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c main.cpp -o main.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"   

make.exe: *** [main.o] Error -1073741819

Execution terminated
```

Comment: Was that really the entire error message ? Nothing from the actual compiler at all ? Just `make` trying to run it, then nothing?

Comment: thats what happens when I press compile and run

Comment: What happens if you try on a commandline prompt `g++.exe --help`?

Comment: There is some doubt on the completeness of your textual information. While you did well to show it in textual form in your question, this is the rare case where you should post a screen shot of the environment which gives you the error message.

Comment: Try a newer version of Dev-C++. 4.9.9.2 is *ancient*.

Comment: DevC++ is not a compiler. It is an IDE. What matters is your C compiler (probably some [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and how it is invoked. Perhaps your `gcc` is too old, incorrectly installed, missing, unavailable.... Learn to use your compiler on the command line in a terminal (and learning all that could take you weeks)

Answer (score 1):

I translated `-1073741819` to hexadecimal number (using Windows calculator):

`-1073741819` = `0xC0000005`

There is a table of all [NTSTATUS Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) on MSDN. The relevant row:

> 0xC0000005 STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
>
> The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

This sounds like OP's `g++` is somehow broken as it looks for me that `make.exe` reports the exit code -1073741819 of `g++`.

In my 20 years professional experience, I had some rare cases where certain specific wrong C++ code made my compiler crashing (instead of just reporting an error). It did not happen for years anymore.

The OP's sample code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int name(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

looks IMHO much too innocent to cause such a compiler bug like mentioned above.

So, I agree with the advice of Yunnosch:

Try `g++ --version` on console (e.g. `cmd.exe`). a) Check of `g++` is runnable at all. b) Have a look whether the version is not too outdated.

You may check also whether concurrent installations of tools with equal name are accidentally mixed somehow. This may happen e.g. by having conflicting locations in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: MinGW 3.4.5, IIRC.

Comment: my understanding is very limited. by that I mean I have just download dev-c++ today and I am trying to learn it so when you say "Try g++ --version on console" I don't understand what you are asking me todo

Comment: @pip4pig Open a `cmd.exe` (the command interpreter) in windows. At the command prompt, type `g++ --version`. (It might be that you have to provide the full path of `g++`.) Press [Enter] and look what happens.

Comment: --help and --version did absolutely nothing. I am downloading a newer version if this doesn't work i am going to try a different IDE

Comment: @pip4pig Console is another word for the textual terminal with some kind of command interpreter. In Windows, it's e.g. the `cmd.exe`, on Linux e.g. an Xterm with a shell (`bash` is very popular). Consoles were exclusively used before Graphical User Interfaces became common. They are still used as console programs are often much easier to write than GUI programs.